# Can ROS work with a Intel® Xeon Prozessor E5620?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
we use a HP Z600, which has two Intel® Xeon Prozessor E5620 using Ubuntu 18.04.
My question is:
Can we run ROS Melodic on this constellation ?
We appreciate your answers.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380224/can-ros-work-with-a-intel%C2%AE-xeon-prozessor-e5620-?/) by [Tricia279](https://answers.ros.org/users/60504/tricia279/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can ROS work with a Intel® Xeon Prozessor E5620 ?

that's a standard `amd64` compatible `x86` CPU with 4 cores, so the answer would be: yes.

See [REP-3: Target Platforms](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) for ROS 1 supported CPU architectures, and [REP-2000: ROS 2 Releases and Target Platforms](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html) for ROS 2 supported CPU architectures.

What made you post this question? Did you read anything which made you ask it?

Note btw: as always with these kind of questions: we can only answer whether the code/binaries are compatible with the CPU architecture. Whether the performance of the specific CPU you mention would be sufficient for your use-cases we cannot say, as only you know those use-cases.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tricia279](https://answers.ros.org/users/60504/tricia279/) on 2021-06-14**:
At :
http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu
is written, that:

> Ubuntu packages are built for the following distros and architectures.

For Distro, Artful and Bionic are only amd64, arm64 and armhf accredited.

So I asked that question, because nowhere is written, that Intel processor are allowed.

Thanks for the quick answer :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-14**:
`amd64` is the generic name for every `x86-64` compatible processor architecture. It's not specific to AMD. Intel uses the same name. See [wikipedia/X86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64).

See also #q354748 and #q311771.